# Why I get ExecuteNonQuery(); error after doing primary key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

After i put CustID int and auto incremental in database it get error.. but after i remove it.. it will be okay to saved in database... the problem now i want to add CustID in int or primarykey that work.. and how do i do pop out/display message like the item was saved?

this is my SQL database..

```
Custid int (could not work) help
custname varchar50
custadd varchar50
custphone varchar
custemail varchar50
```

these is my code :

```
public partial class NewCase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con =new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\WebSite6\\App_Data\\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from aspnet_Customer");

public void Bind()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    con.Open();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    da.Fill(ds, "aspnet_Customer");
    con.Close();
}


protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand comi = new SqlCommand("Insert into aspnet_Customer values (@Custname,@Custaddress,@Custemail,@Custphone)");
    comi.Parameters.Add("Custname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    comi.Parameters["Custname"].Value = TextBox3.Text;
    comi.Parameters.Add("Custaddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    comi.Parameters["Custaddress"].Value = TextBox9.Text;
    comi.Parameters.Add("Custemail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    comi.Parameters["Custemail"].Value = TextBox10.Text;
    comi.Parameters.Add("Custphone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    comi.Parameters["Custphone"].Value = TextBox11.Text;


    comi.Connection = con;
    comi.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Message.box("DATA ADDED SUCCESSFULLY!!");
    Bind();

}
```

}

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: you already answer it , yes because i didt put insert "table value".. the message.box also is an error too but i just removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must list column names in `INSERT INTO` clause in case if you have autoincrement column, so you can't insert all columns (your autoincrement column generates automatically).

```
SqlCommand comi = new SqlCommand(
            "Insert into aspnet_Customer( Custname, Custaddress, Custemail, Custphone)
                  values (@Custname,@Custaddress,@Custemail,@Custphone)");
```

Comment: If you want to use multiple lines string, you have to use _verbatim string literal_.

Comment: YES, thanks you it worked now. yeah i totally forget about that .. now that fresh my memory back....